# P(X>max(Y,Z)) for independent normal variables

Tags: probability

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be independent random variables, drawn from normal distributions with different means but with the same variance, how would one compute $P(X>\text{max}(Y,Z))$?

Let's say $\mu = [1.3, 0.1, 2.25]$ and $\sigma = 1$, if anyone wants to try it with real numbers (for which I have an answer by simulation).

More generally, how would one compute the probability of a sample drawn from $\mathcal{N}_x$ being the greatest in the set of samples drawn from $[\mathcal{N}_{1:n}]$?

---

Related:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/probability-of-one-random-variable-being-greater-than-another/431484#431484
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462137/what-can-we-say-about-pxy-and-xz
- https://doi.org/10.1037/0033-2909.111.2.361
- https://doi.org/10.3102/10769986025002101

---

Edited:

- to correct accidentally flipped > sign
- to update the terminology to include `max`

Comment: Have you tried conditioning on the probability that Y < Z?

Comment: hint: jointly distributed random variables (i.e. random vectors)

Comment: You want to condition on the value of $X$.  In particular use the law of total probability in integral form by conditioning on $\{X=x\}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I think this question is answered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475242/how-can-i-estimate-the-probability-of-a-random-variable-from-one-population-bein?rq=1

Comment: Yes I think so too